# Nginx website not available through domain name, available through curl or IP

Tags: nginx

When trying to request the server by domain name on Firefox it seems like trying to connect but finally give up.

When I connect through IP or using curl everything is ok.

Few days ago I was able to connect by Firefox but of course configuration was different as I am playing a bit with nginx which is new to me.

Configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/test/;
        server_name www.domainname.com;
        index index.html;

}
```

Comment: Does the domain name point to the correct IP address? Are you connecting using `http` or `https`? Have you tried completely resetting the browser?

Comment: Complete resetting browser worked. Thanks